# Class constructor ObjectId cannot be invoked without 'new' in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, objectid

When I send data from frontend to backend via API request I got this error:

> Class constructor ObjectId can not be invoked without 'new' in mongoose,

I tried to convert into string and also into int but it didn't work.....

Comment: Find where uses `ObjectId`  class, create it like `new ObjectId()` not `ObjectId()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am new to nodejs too, i am trying to post some questions, even answers that i am not able to find.

Here the problem not from frontend and backend, it is from mongoose schema

> when we are converting data to objectId we just need to declare new

.

Solution: **new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(Id)**

*If you find helpful then like the answer so others reach fast.*

Comment: is it a problem of the newest version of mongodb node package? I used mongodb 4.9.1 on Node.js before, and never needed to add "new" before objectId

Comment: I told it is in mongoose, i found this when i use react frontend.

Answer (score 7):

```
Object id = "649beed348b20e1b8e7bca95";
```

You can pass this like:

```
new ObjectId(id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add the **new** keyword in front of objectId() function, it will work. For example:

> const documentToFind = { _id: **new ObjectId("649beed348b20e1b8e7bca95")** };

There is the difference in the usage of **objectId** function in the driver connection for nodejs where you have need use it as constructor. Reference: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.6/classes/BSON.ObjectId.html

If you are using the function in the MongoDB directly for query, you can use

> **ObjectId("649beed348b20e1b8e7bca95")**

Reference: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.3/reference/method/ObjectId/#examples

Answer (score 1):

If you're encountering an issue with Mongoose version 8 or above, ensure that you instantiate a new instance of the Product model using the "new" keyword :

```
const product = Product({
_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
name: req.body.name,
price:req.body.price
```

});

Replace it with

```
const product = new Product({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    name: req.body.name,
    price:req.body.price
  });
```

Add "new" keyword at line 1 and 2.